# Teamcity failing to update a directory on agent machines

Tags: mercurial, teamcity, agent, vcs-checkout

Checkout is failing on feature branches on agent machines. Works fine on default branch. I have checked all agent machines have correct host fingerprints. Teamcity user has full administrative rights on machine but it is still failing to checkout.

> Failed to start reason
>   Error while applying patch: Failed to perform checkout on agent: '"c:\program files\mercurial\hg.exe" --config ui.interactive=False update --config auth.tc.prefix=* --config auth.tc.username=test--config auth.tc.password=****** --config "auth.tc.schemes=http https" -C -r 2240521534ea'
>   command failed.

Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: Can you run that command manually on the build agent?

Comment: Did you use a personal build in that checkout on that machine?
This happened to me a few times in the past - I found that rolling back to a previous revision and discarding changes worked more often than not.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, Yes I can run it fine using command manually on build agant. Its just with the teamcity that it keeps failing. Also tried doing a clean checkout and even by creating a new VCS root but it just fails for the feature branch and works fine for default branch. please guide

Comment: Are you running the command on the build agent from the build agent work directory that it failed in (check the build log for the exact folder), and did you run it under the same user.

Comment: I used the following command on build agent using the same user accoutn: C:\Program Files\Mercurial>hg.exe clone https://hg.test.co.uk/test#1.8-dev
 Z:\testbranch.

Answer (score 0):

In our team we've choosen to enforce [clean checkout](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Clean+Checkout) after few similar incidents.  This is quick solution.  Our repository is about 800 Mbytes but fast LAN saves us.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't make any difference. I think the problem lies in the way Mercurial works. This "remote host closed connection" crap is really annoying. Maybe TeamCity doesn't really care about Mercurial anymore and that's the reason why the problems are more frequent lately.... If I had time and clue, I would have switched to Git long ago. I just think the probability of not getting the change history transferred is too high. I haven't seen any serious professional import tools anywhere so far.